# Unhelpful SQL/PHP error

Tags: php, sql, mysqli

EDIT: I think I figured out what is happening! The Variable $string is set to be a post value, so when I run the comment code it is overriding the Post value with its own and setting $string to be nothing, breaking the page. Any ideas how to fix?

I'm running a piece of code for a simple website that should submit a comment entered into a form into the database, but when I click the submit button for the comment it just gives me this error message:

```
Database access failed1: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1
```

The code for the page in question is:

```
<?php
require_once('checklog.php');
require_once("functions.php");
require_once('../Website/recaptcha/recaptchalib.php');
//Include external php files. Functions contains functions, Checklog redirects the user to the login page if they are not logged in. Checklog also contains session_start(). If you remove it make sure to add session_start() to this page.
$db_hostname = 'localhost'; 
$db_database = 'removed'; 
$db_username = 'removed'; 
$db_password = 'removed'; 
$db_status = 'not initialised'; 
$str_result = ''; 
$str_options = ''; 
$db_server = mysqli_connect($db_hostname, $db_username, $db_password); 
$db_status = "connected";

$string = $_POST ['filmID'];

    mysqli_select_db($db_server, $db_database); 
    $query = "SELECT FilmName, GenreName, DirName, Synopsis FROM Films JOIN Genres JOIN Directors WHERE Directors.DirID = Films.DirID AND Films.GenreID = Genres.GenreID AND Films.FilmID = $string"; 
    $resultcount = 1;
    $result = mysqli_query($db_server, $query); 
    if (!$result) die("Database access failed1: " . mysqli_error($db_server)); 
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){ 
        $FilmName = $row['FilmName']; 
        $GenreName = $row['GenreName'];
        $DirName = $row['DirName'];
        $Synopsis = $row['Synopsis'];
    } 
    mysqli_free_result($result); 

    $query = "SELECT username, Rating, Comment FROM Comments JOIN Users WHERE Comments.UserID = Users.UserID AND Comments.FilmID = $string"; 
    $commentnum = 1;
    $result = mysqli_query($db_server, $query); 
    if (!$result) die("Database access failed2: " . mysqli_error($db_server)); 
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){ 
        $str_comments .= "<p>" . $commentnum . " - Review by " . $row['username'] . ": " . $row['Comment'] . " [" . $row['Rating'] . "/5]</p>"; 
        $commentnum = $commentnum + 1;
    } 
    mysqli_free_result($result); 

if(trim($_POST['submit']) == "Submit"){ 

        $privatekey= "6Lem4-gSAAAAADsaa9KXlzSAhLs8Ztp83Lt-x1kn";
        $resp = recaptcha_check_answer ($privatekey,
                                $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"],
                                $_POST["recaptcha_challenge_field"],
                                $_POST["recaptcha_response_field"]);
        $message = " ";
        if (!$resp->is_valid) {
            //incorrect entry
            $message = "The reCAPTCHA wasn't entered correctly. Go back and try again.
            (reCAPTCHA said: " . $resp->error . ")";
            //recaptcha validation
        } else  {


            //Submit the reviews
            $comment = clean_string($db_server, $_POST['comment']); 
            $rating = clean_string($db_server, $_POST['rating']);
            $user = $SESSION['UserID'];
            if ($comment != '') { 
                $queryreview = "INSERT INTO Comments (Comment, Rating, UserID, FilmID) VALUES ('$comment', '$rating', '$user', '$string')";  
                mysqli_select_db($db_server, $db_database); 
                 mysqli_query($db_server, $queryreview) or 
                die("Insert failed: " . mysqli_error($db_server)); 

            }

        } 
    }


?>

<html>
<head>
<title>View individual film details.</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Welcome to the site, <?php echo $_SESSION['username']; ?> ! You are user ID <?php echo $_SESSION['userid'] ?>.</h1>
<p>This film is called <?php echo $FilmName ?> and is a <?php echo $GenreName; ?> film directed by <?php echo $DirName; ?></p>
<p>Synopsis: <?php echo $Synopsis; ?> </p></body>
<p>Reviews:
<?php echo $str_comments ?></p>

<form id="frmComments" action="viewfilm.php" method="post">     
        <p>Have you seen this movie? Leave a review and tell other users what you thought.</p> 
        review: <textarea rows="2" cols="30" name="comment"></textarea> </p>
        <p>Rating: <select name="rating">
            <option value="1">1</option>
            <option value="2">2</option>
            <option value="3">3</option>
             <option value="4">4</option>
             <option value="5">5</option>
             </select>
            <?php
                $publickey = "6Lem4-gSAAAAAMHLAVbieIknMtUZo71ZKzzCkoFN";
                echo recaptcha_get_html($publickey);
            ?>
       <input type="submit" id="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
    </form>

</body>
</html>
```

The piece of code that should be running the comment insertion is

```
if(trim($_POST['submit']) == "Submit"){ 


    $privatekey= "6Lem4-gSAAAAADsaa9KXlzSAhLs8Ztp83Lt-x1kn";
    $resp = recaptcha_check_answer ($privatekey,
                            $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"],
                            $_POST["recaptcha_challenge_field"],
                            $_POST["recaptcha_response_field"]);
    $message = " ";
    if (!$resp->is_valid) {
        //incorrect entry
        $message = "The reCAPTCHA wasn't entered correctly. Go back and try again.
        (reCAPTCHA said: " . $resp->error . ")";
        //recaptcha validation
    } else  {


        //Submit the reviews
        $comment = clean_string($db_server, $_POST['comment']); 
        $rating = clean_string($db_server, $_POST['rating']);
        $user = $SESSION['UserID'];
        if ($comment != '') { 
            $queryreview = "INSERT INTO Comments (Comment, Rating, UserID, FilmID) VALUES ('$comment', '$rating', '$user', '$string')";  
            mysqli_select_db($db_server, $db_database); 
             mysqli_query($db_server, $queryreview) or 
            die("Insert failed: " . mysqli_error($db_server)); 

        }

    } 
}
```

But as you can see by the "1" included in the error message, the error is pointing to the earlier query that is used to generate the page content. Thing is this query does work, it is only after clicking submit on a comment that I get this error.

Comment: This error is shows that your query is not correct. This error is comes from your database.

Comment: Try INSERT INTO Comments (Comment, Rating, UserID, FilmID) VALUES ('$comment', '$rating', $user, $string) you are passing only one string

Comment: That hasn't fixed it but that was going to probably bite me in the arse later, thanks for pointing that out Nouphal.

Comment: are UserID and FilmID int or string?

Comment: `SELECT FilmName, GenreName, DirName, Synopsis FROM Films JOIN Genres JOIN Directors WHERE Directors.DirID = Films.DirID AND Films.GenreID = Genres.GenreID AND Films.FilmID = '$string'`. If you want to insert a variable string into a sql statement you've to quotes.

Comment: it says `Database access failed1` but in your comments its `Insert failed:`

Comment: UserID and FilmID are both integers

Comment: @ GuyT Doing that will make it run the query but with some problems, both FilmID and USerID come out as 0 in the database entry. It also breaks the queries that i'm actually changing and prevents the film info from actually being viewed.

Comment: @user3201991: can you tell marked your line number in which you got error?

Comment: @Nouphal that means that the error is occurring further up the page. Look at the full code, there are three chunks of sql code and "failed1" points to the first of them.

Comment: @Awlad it says line 1 in the error message but that seems to be incorrect since there's nothing up there. The actual error message originated from line 22: if (!$result) die("Database access failed1: " . mysqli_error($db_server));  which is a separate set of SQL code entirely to the one being run

Comment: it seems that you also have error in checklog.php

Comment: Pretty sure not, checklog is very simple and has been running correctly in multiple uses before this. I think I figured out what is happening, edited in above.

Comment: @AwladLiton: it is an MySQL error, the error occured in the first line of submitted SQL code, not in the PHP part. Regarding the edit: if I understand the code right, you don't have a field `'filmID'` in the comments `<form>` -> add it as a `<input type="hidden" name="filmID" value="' . $string . '"/>'` element. Also: your code is vulnerable to SQL injection attacks! if you develop this further, sanitize the user input and/or use prepared statements

Comment: Where exactly is it vulnerable to SQL injection? If you mean through the comments box here the clean_string function that it runs through is located in the FUnctions.php file and handles input sanitizing.

Comment: that's good, didn't look too close at all parameter. At least `$string = $_POST['filmID']` is vulnerable - there are a lot of tools to intercept and manipulate http (POST) data, so even hidden fields in forms are not safe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the probem is indeed the $string variabe that is being sent empty.

There are different ways to solve this issue here are some ideas:

- Use a hidden field in the form where the value of the posted filmID is stored and sent again after submitting.
- Store the filmID value in the Session global.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

if you need to give string in your values then set variable inside quotation like this:

Change

```
$queryreview = "INSERT INTO Comments (Comment, Rating, UserID, FilmID) VALUES ('$comment, $rating, $user, $string')"
```

to

```
$queryreview = "INSERT INTO Comments (Comment, Rating, UserID, FilmID) VALUES ('$comment', '$rating', '$user', '$string')"
```

Comment: See below. Valid point but hasn't fixed my problem. Thanks anyway